# jQuery parallel autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete attached to an textbox input element which works fine.
I have a special requirement in which I would need to have two dropdowns appear with different data. So the user would type in the input textbox and as he is typing it would show two dropdowns side by side and filter both at the same time depending on what he is typing.

Anyone know how I could achieve this ?

Comment: You should include some kind of code - esp. a JSFiddle or some other information on something you have tried.

Comment: Example at  : https://jsfiddle.net/wpr9t3wr/1/ as the user types in the Tags input element, the filtered dropdown appears with the availableTags1 data array. But what I need is to have two dropdowns appear side by side - one with the availableTags1 array as the data source and another one with the availableTags2 array as the datasource. They would both be filtered as the user types.

Comment: I am getting closer https://jsfiddle.net/6hw75wst/3/ however I need to find a way to hide the second input element but still have it react as if it where visible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)? I've provided an example of a `keyup` check using jQuery, and then a simple `Select2` call on another select so you can see the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
 var $options = $('#test').find('option');
    var selected = false;
    
    $options.each(function() {
      var $option = $(this);  
        var text = $option.text()
        
        if( !selected && text.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            $option.prop('selected', true);
            selected = true;
        }
    });
});

$('#test2').select2();
  });
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input type="text" />
<br />
<select id="test">
    <option></option>
    <option val="1">Testing</option>
    <option val="2">Why Not?</option>
    <option val="3">Use</option>
    <option val="4">Select2?</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select id="test2">
    <option></option>
    <option val="1">See</option>
    <option val="2">It's</option>
    <option val="3">Much</option>
    <option val="4">Better</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```